# Why does my JQuery AJAX call execute twice, but only if it's not called first?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

On my portfolio website, I am using a jQuery `.ajax()` call to pull in my portfolio pieces via XML.

My issue is that after a fresh page load, if the "portfolio" link is clicked *first*, then the portfolio pieces are pulled in normally. If, after a fresh page load, the "portfolio" link is clicked *after* any of the other links, then the portfolio pieces are pulled in twice.

You can see the issue for yourself on my site: [Transhuman Creative](http://www.transhumancreative.com)

Here is the code that figures out which navigation link is clicked based on its `rel` attribute:

```
$("#nav a").click( function () {
    if($(this).attr("rel") == "blog") {
        return false;
    }else{
        $("#nav a").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        setBlock($(this).attr("rel"));
    }
});
```

After a link is clicked, it is processed by theThe `setBlock()` function, which hides existing content and calls the `processBlock()` function to load content.

```
function setBlock(block) {
    if(firstNav) {
        processBlock(block);
        firstNav = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if($(".tab").length > 0 && $(".tab").is(":hidden") == false) {
            $(".hidable").fadeOut();
            $(".tab").fadeOut(function(){
                processBlock(block);
            });
        }
        else {
            $(".hidable").fadeOut(function (){
                processBlock(block);
            });
        }       
    }
}
```

The `processBlock()` function waits 500ms to let the animation finish, then either shows the block of content or calls the `loadItems()` function to load the portfolio data.

```
function processBlock(block) {
    var s = setInterval( function () {
        if (block == "portfolio") {         
            loadItems();            
        }else{          
            $("." + block).fadeIn();
        }
        clearInterval(s);
    }, 500);
}
```

And finally, the `.ajax()` call is in the `loadItems()` function. After loading the porfolio data from the XML file, it calls the `tabFade()` function to parse the data and generate the HTML for the portfolio pieces. The variable `firstCall` is initially set to `true`, and it is meant to prevent the portfolio data from being reloaded if it's already in memory:

```
function loadItems() {
    if (firstCall) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "data/portfolio.xml?ver=1.11",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml){
                $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
                    $("#main").append(addItem($(this)));
                });
                tabFade();
                firstCall = false;
            }
        });
    }else{
        tabFade();
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on what might be causing the double load issue? Thanks for your help.

Comment: josh cool site, I have a tip for you: On your main links instead of using `href="#"` use `href="javascript:void(0)"` you won't get the # sign in your URL when you click the link.

Comment: I would actually recommend the common hash-bang. Allow for bookmarking and forward-back capability (and [Google-supported](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html))

Comment: @Brad Christie, if you use a # what is there to go forward and backwards to? The site wasn't redirected to another page.

Comment: @Nick: [oh, no?](http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/Xn4wN/) Click an anchor and go through them, then use your browser's back button.

Comment: @Brad Christie, I was specifically talking about his web site and specifically his nav bar that doesn't implement bookmarking functionality (or need to).

Comment: Thanks for this discussion; it has given me a few things to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it would be better to set the firstCall variable right inside of the if condition. Otherwise it waits 500+ milliseconds before being set and only gets set once the ajax request completes.

```
function loadItems() {
    if (firstCall) {
        firstCall = false; // Put the assignment here before waiting.
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "data/portfolio.xml?ver=1.11",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml){
                $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
                    $("#main").append(addItem($(this)));
                });
                tabFade();
                //firstCall = false;
            }
        });
    }else{
        tabFade();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using setTimeout instead of setInterval. You probably want to use setTimeout anyway as I don't think you want to run the code more than once?

It could be that it's running that code twice and making two ajax calls as it hasn't responded within 500ms.

Comment: I agree that it should be "setTimeout()" instead of "setInterval()", but the interval timer should be cleared by his handler when the first iteration runs.

Comment: `setTimeout()` is more logical, and while it didn't fix the problem, I appreciate you mentioning it.